# svn project with linked common files

Tags: svn, links

The src directory of my project is composed by three folders: two sub-projects and some common files.
I linked the files of the common directory to the two sub-projects.
I've just imported my project to svn but end up with three duplications of the content of the common directory.
I'm wondering if svn can deal with this and how. Like an option which specify to not consider links.
I thought about deleting in svn linked files from the sub-projects.
Thank you,

```
 Éric.
```

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/48623/do-symbolic-link-files-survive-svn
Perhaps client issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have to read about and learn SVN externals with all their pro and contra and use (where it's possible) SVN-, not OS-specific tools

PS - And using SVN-jargon and terms and objects will make readers happier: we can not guess the translation of read into Subversion objects and task.

Subversion know nothing about projects/subprojects/subsubprojects etc... We know "repository", "repository-tree", "working copy"

Answer (score 0):

why not isolate the 'shared' files into one single seperate repo? and just list your repo as a deployable dependency, that way they are always up to date from that repo, and you are NOT duplicating files.

This ultimately is a question of organization.  How you organize your dependencies.